# Python CSV writer for dynamic headers

Tags: python, csv

I have many dictionaries which are not consistent in term of keys, I have to write them to CSV.

While using `DictWriter`, it requires to define the headers at declaration which I don't know. I also can't store them in list till I have had all the `dict` as the count of `dict` run into millions.

I'm in search of library that I can keep on writing CSV with inconsistent rows, and it manages them below the hood.

Data :

```
{'a':'1','i':'1','l':None}
{'b':'1','k':'1','y':None}
{'g':'1','k':'1','j':None}
{'b':'1','h':'1','c':None}
{'b':'1','h':'1','n':None}
{'a':'1','b':'1','v':None}
{'a':'1','b':'1','c':None}
```

Expected Output: (CSV like this)

```
a   c   b   g   i   h   k   j   l   n   v   y
1               1                           
        1               1                   
            1           1                   
        1           1                       
        1           1                       
1       1                                   
1       1
```

This data on top, is coming from iterator, can't store it in memory as it's very large.

Comment: The csv module is enough, with a list of the keys found so long. but it will be impossible the write the header line until you know all the keys...

Comment: yeah, the data range in mills so no definite way of knowing all the headers.

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? Currently your question is rather *unclear*...

Comment: @SergeBallesta have updated the question hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: a part of the answer lies in what you can to happen if a new key comes up, or do you know the possible keys beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know all the header fields and you think it's inefficient to iterate the iterable of dicts to collect the header fields, then you should not be using `DictWriter`.

You can instead keep track of all seen fields, writing them as they appear in each dict and appending new fields to the end of each new row; so that newer fields are at the tail of the rows in the file. Existing fields not found in new rows are written as blanks.

Here's a toy code in Python 3 that demonstrates the concept:

```
import io
import csv

# supposedly lengthy iterator containing dicts
it = iter([{'name': 'Bob', 'house': 5, 'cell': 8090}, 
           {'name': 'Lisa', 'class': 12, 'age': 53}, 
           {'done': False, 'flat': 6}])
# simulate file
s = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(s)

header, header_set = [], set()
writer.writerow('') # place holder for header
for row in it:
    for key in row:
       if key not in header_set:
           header_set.add(key)
           header.append(key)
    writer.writerow(row.get(col, '') for col in header)


# TEST: recover written file as iterable of dicts using DictReader
s.seek(0)
reader = csv.DictReader(s, fieldnames=header, restval='')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

---

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('house', '5'), ('cell', '8090'), ('class', ''), ('age', ''), ('done', ''), ('flat', '')])
OrderedDict([('name', 'Lisa'), ('house', ''), ('cell', ''), ('class', '12'), ('age', '53'), ('done', ''), ('flat', '')])
OrderedDict([('name', ''), ('house', ''), ('cell', ''), ('class', ''), ('age', ''), ('done', 'False'), ('flat', '6')])
```

---

If you need to update the existing file with the header, you can do write the header to a new file, and write all the rows from the previous file into the successive lines:

```
new_file.write(','.join(header)+s.read())
```

However, considering your initial claim that the number of rows is quite large, you can avoid the memory intensive `file.read`, by manually copying the header into the existing file using a file editor :)

Comment: Thanks, I had this in mind. But I want to reduce the lookups.

Will probably go with this and modify it a little, throwing `map` to optimize i

Comment: Note that lookup is O(1) with sets, and that's why I'm not looking up directly on the list.

Comment: I have 42 million rows with 270 keys. So lot of lookups.